In the searchbar in windows how do I show all textfiles? thank you
I want to search an external drive to show all text files, i've tried *.txt and ext: - neither work - can anyone help? kind regards

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry i have windows explorer open on a external hard drive - in the searchbox on the top right when i type txt or *.txt nothing shows up even though there are text files (.txt) on the drive, hopefully that is enough info....

[Edit] the question and add information there, do not hide it in comments.

If you can't get Windows Explorer to do what you want, you could try ...

open a command prompt window
change to the external drive using the drive letter as a command e.g. f:
change to the subdirectory you want to start the search at e.g. cd \
search for filenames using dir /S *.txt


can you let me know how to find in sub directories also

The /S option (not \s) will make it search subdirectories

^^ This. Or dir /s *.txt > c:\ListOfFiles.txt if you want a record of the txt files in another text file.
Another option, if you don't mind downloading a free program, would be to use Agent Ransack, which gives you a GUI interface and would let you narrow down the search to, for example, *.TXT files with specific content, created before/after certain dates, and would show you sample content in a preview pane or let you launch the files if you wish.

Used Agent Ransack - fantastic - thank you very much
